# Spree/Deface - Conditionally set an override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

Is there a way to conditionally set a deface override, for example based on product?

So product == 'x', then do it, otherwise, ignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet will be to conditionally use render_original like so:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "products", 
                     :name => "example", 
                     :surround => "div#products",
                     :text => "<% if @product == 'x' %><%# do something %><% else %><%= render_original %><% end %>")
```

Comment: Sorry, as I am fairly new to deface, is "render_original" built in command?

Comment: Yes.  It is built in, however after reviewing the code, I believe it only works with surround or surround_contents.  I've updated the snippet above to use surround.